# EclEmma covarage eclipse plugin failed with build directory

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, eclemma

I changed my build path to

> my-project/build

in order Eclipse to take the class files from the Gradle execution, but when I rerun coverage analysis I faced this problem.

```
Error while loading coverage session (code 5001). Error while analyzing package fragment root java at my-project/build (code 5007). Error while analyzing MyClass.class.
```

How to configure  EclEmma in order to use class files from build, not bin folder?

Comment: What is your default output folder (in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Source_ at the bottom)? Does changing the classpath of the coverage configuration work (_Run Coverage..._)?

Comment: IN my source option is my-project/build.(when ins my-project/bin coverage is working) How to change the classpath of the coverage configuration?

Comment: Coverage configuration: via menu _Run >  Coverage..._ or Ctrl+click _Coverage_ button in main toolbar.

Comment: I do not have such with STS. I do not why..

Comment: Switch to the _Java_ perspective.

Comment: Sorry. When I switch to Java Perspective Run->Covarage.. all src folders are marked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155847/discussion-between-howlger-and-xelian).